# HTML5 Canvas to JAVAFX canvas

Tags: javascript, java, html, canvas, javafx

I port my game from HTML5 Canvas to JAVAFX canvas, but i had problem in this part

```
canvasHTML.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
```

And i dont know how i can reach this line in code in JAVAFX Canvas, because there is only method

```
javafxCanv.setGlobalBlendMode(BlendMode)
```

I take a look at BlendMode enums, but there isnt DEST_OUT :(, can somone help me how to handle "destination-out" ? I needed this to clear custom shape on my canvas

Comment: I suspect you can assign a [clip Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#clipProperty) to your Canvas to achieve a similar effect.